# Payu payment gateway integration with PHP

Tags: php, payu

PayU provide lot of API. I don't know which API is used. I want to integrate with lots of option like,

1. Credit card option
2. Debit card option
3. Web checkout option

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. As written, your question is too broad because _"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."_

Answer (score 0):

Most Recommended way is use Direct Payment Gateway Provider's API rather than others.
IF your are using PayU biz :
 Step 1: You can use simple HTML form enter into payu payment gateway
 Step 2: You can use official payu SDK [PayU SDK](https://github.com/PayU/openpayu_php)
If you are using PayU Money :
 You can download PHP API from merchant login page.
In general payment gateway provider will provide Credit/Debit and netbanking options.

Comment: This is ok, I use this api "SDK PayU SDK". I use simple HTML form for payment gatway. But I want to express checkout link credit card and Debit card. 
What about this API "http://developers.payulatam.com/en/api/payments.html" Check it and please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To
integrate Payumoney in woocommerce "PayU" provides a simple plugin to
integrate. Install it, enter your credential and that’s all.. Done..

If you want to integrate it in wordpress non e-commerce site, it needs customization. Install PHP kit provided by payumoney through FTP file upload or web hosting control panel.

The
most important you have to pass the values of all required parameter as
mentioned in their documentation. Pass these values with $_POST. That’s
it.

I have done the same thing in Hotel Booking system. Its working fine.If you need any further help, contact me on [aryamaae.com](http://aryamaae.com)